# Getting "multipart: NextPart: EOF" error when reading multipart/form-data

Tags: api, http, go, multipartform-data, go-gin

I am building a router layer for an API where I take the response and extract a parameter (in this case a `service_code`, the name can vary - `service_code`, `serviceCode`, `code` need to handle all) from the request body and pass it to the service that needs it. The data can be in raw json format `application/json` , query params, path params or as form data `multipart/form-data`. I am able to do it with the others but with form, when I pass the payload to the destination service I get the error `multipart: NextPart: EOF`.

Here is how I am reading the data:

```golang
c.MultipartForm()
postForm := c.Request.PostForm
queryParams := c.Request.URL.Query()
route := c.Request.URL.Path
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)

serviceCode, destUrl, payload := getCityCode(queryParams, route, body, postForm)
```

Then I pass this payload to `http.NewRequest`

```golang
http.NewRequest(method, destUrl, strings.NewReader(payload))
```

At the destination when I read the data:

```golang
data := models.Data{}
err := c.Bind(&data); err != nil {
  c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
  return
}
```

The error is `multipart: NextPart: EOF`. Can someone help please!

Answer (score -1):

This error happens when the form is empty because you are reading all the stream data with `ioutil` before binding it. You should change your code to use the information you need after binding it.